# Logview in Imshow

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logarithmic yscale in imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478460/logarithmic-yscale-in-imshow)

In my imshow view, I want the logarithmic scale in the `y`. the answers like `yscale('log')` is not my answer. any suggestion please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478460/logarithmic-yscale-in-imshow

Comment: more info in above topic which is already closed

Comment: When a question is closed, please do not post a new question on the exact same subject. If you want to discuss close reasons, please use the [meta] site instead. This question is now a duplicate of your original question.

Comment: You can edit the old question to make it clear that it is not a duplicate itself, then request it to be reopened.

Comment: Sorry, i did it because they closed the topic even after i described them my question and told them that these answers are not correct. They even didn't listen to me. Can you help me what should i do now? where is MSO?

Comment: Corrected my comment to link correctly. MSO stands for meta.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want the yaxis to be the "log scale" of the data your are plotting in the plot?  The difficulty of doing this with imshow() is that the structure in y is fundamentally linear, that is, imshow just shows *everything* as it's structured in the dataset.

A hack would be to simply copy more data into the plot in such a way that the data reflects a log distribution, so the "lower values" are weighted within the set.

Another track to take would be to try a meshgrid approach, this answer for a different question may help there:

[Python matplotlib - formatting with meshgrid for user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896130/python-matplotlib-formatting-with-meshgrid-for-user-defined-function)

Comment: this is exactly what i thought. I should duplicate the rows exponentially. Thank you for the response.